# Передать число из var в скрипт

Tags: javascript

Со страницы берется число, условно это 2.7, через alert оно выводится корректно.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    var e = document.getElementById("pweight");
    var pweight = e.textContent || e.innerText;
});
```

Каким образом мне его передать дальше в скрипт калькулятора

```
var widjet = new ISDEKWidjet({
    showWarns: true,
    showErrors: true,
    showLogs: true,
    defaultCity: 'Москва',
    cityFrom: 'Балашиха',
    link: 'forpvz',
    goods: [{
        length: 1,
        width: 1.3,
        height: 4.5,
        weight: echo "$pweight" //Сюда
    }],
});
```

Comment: weight: pweight, так?

Comment: Первое что пробовал. В консоли браузера ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: pweight is not defined"

Comment: Самый примитивный вариант - объявить переменную глобально: `window.pweight = e.textContent...`, и потом также ее достать `weight: window.pweight`.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures

Comment: Получил такую ошибку "Value must be an array of objects of type {length:(float),width:(float),height(float),weight(float)}"

Как это число из html в float превратить?

Comment: просто объявите var pweight вне функций, то есть как глобальную. А в листенере соответственно уберите var перед этой переменной, а далее как указал @Solo_777